# Segmentation fault when pointer is local

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

I´m getting a segmentation fault with a pointer when it´s declared as local. The program is too long to copy it here, but it´s something like this:

```
void f(){
    int* p;
    int n = 0;
    for (...) {
        n++;
        p = realloc(p, n * sizeof(int));
        if (p == NULL) error(); 
    }
    //Code using the pointer
    free(p);
}

int main() {
    f();
    puts("Finish");
}
```

the puts("Finish"); is executed, but i get a segmentation fault after this.

If I declare p as global, before the funcion, it works perfectly without the fault and this problem gets solved but I dont know why is this happening.

Running the debugger I can´t see where the problem is, all values seem ok. This is the trace after the fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000361206dbd1 in _IO_flush_all_lockp () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000361206dbd1 in _IO_flush_all_lockp () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000361206e725 in _IO_cleanup () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000036120334b2 in exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000361201d99b in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000400ce9 in _start ()
```

Just in case it can be an issue, it´s an multiprocess application (fork, execv, etc...)

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you don't bother to initialize `p` -- with a global var it will be implicitly initialized to 0, but a local var is not.  So you end up calling realloc/free with a random garbage pointer that corrupts the heap and causes a later crash...

Initialize `p` and that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. A simple int* p = NULL fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* p;
// ...
for (...) {
//...
       p = realloc(p, n * sizeof(int));
```

In the first iteration of the loop, the value of `p` is ill-defined because you have not initialized it. This is an error. Not sure that it is the cause of your problem, but I'd fix that first and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation for `realloc`.  It's available here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/realloc.html

The thing to take away is that calling `realloc()` with a `NULL` pointer (i.e. a pointer that points at 0) is valid.  However calling it with a non-null pointer that was not obtained using  `malloc` or `calloc` causes "undefined" behavior.

So why does this matter?  Because when you declare `p` in the global scope it will be initialized to 0 (i.e. `NULL`) for you.  When it is declared in the local scope this does not/may not happen.  Instead it will just have some arbitrary initial value, if you do not explicitly initialize it, and this will cause the aforementioned "undefined behavior".